# Why the Python 2, 3 compatibility package is named `six`?

Tags: python, six

Six provides simple utilities for wrapping over differences between Python 2 and Python 3. It is intended to support codebases that work on both Python 2 and 3 without modification. six consists of only one Python file, so it is painless to copy into a project.

I was always wondering why it is named `six`.

Comment: I am guessing `2 * 3 = 6`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> The name, “six”, comes from the fact that 2*3 equals 6. Why not
>   addition? Multiplication is more powerful, and, anyway, “five” has
>   already been snatched away by the (admittedly now moribund) Zope Five
>   project.

[Source](https://six.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: The "six" package is not only for python2 (for code to work on python3) but also the other way round, so `3*2=6` as well;)